# Class Declaration Questions

Tags: c++

From this code snippet:

```
CClassA& CClassA::operator =(const CClassA& rhs)
{
     return;
}
```

I have the following questions:

1. Is it a class member?
2. What does `&` mean?
3. What does `rhs` mean? (I only know it means "right hand side")
4. What does `const` mean?

Comment: Note that this won't compile. Also, the `&` in this case means "reference" not "address of".

Comment: You should really have a [good book](http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks) explain this to you, learning by internet/guess/trial-and-error is going to harm you in the long run.

Comment: @GMan: Excellent point. It's really important to know this stuff well, otherwise large quantities of heartache and frustration await you in the future. Learning from a good textbook is generally better than cobbling knowledge together from various internet sources.

Comment: Thanks, will attached  a good book in the long run.
Just wanted to get to the solution faster for some occasion.

Answer (score 3):

1. It is a "member function." It is actually an *overloaded assignment operator*, which defines what to do when you assign an instance of a `CClassA` to another `CClassA` instance. e.g.

   CClassA foo;
   CClassA bar;
   foo = bar; // This will call the overloaded assignment operator.
2. The `&` in this case means "reference". That is, the function returns a `CClassA` reference and takes a `const CClassA` reference as an argument. This is in contrast with passing by value, which would send a copy of the `CClassA` instance to the function. A reference just passes the address of the instance to avoid the overhead of copying the instance.
3. Yes, "rhs" means right-hand side. In my example `foo = bar;`, you are actually saying `foo.operator=(bar);`.
4. `const` in this case means a *constant reference*. This means that the `rhs` will not be changed inside the function.

As @Seth Carnegie commented, this code won't compile. You are expected to return a `CClassA&`, but you are returning nothing.

Comment: Thank you, very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

1 ) This is a class member. you are trying to overload operator = . Go through [this link](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html)
 it has got more help on the topic

2) & means you are passing  reference

3) rhs means right hand hand side

4) const here means normal semantics of constant i.e. you do not want to alter the rhs side

**Most important thing is that when you are going to have 
CClass a,b;
and then a=b;
then this would be equivalent to calling 
a.operator=b**